# Setting textarea value with Jquery taking too much time on android's Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm using a textarea to send an image DataURL (more than 15k characters). Doing it on my computer is almost instantaneous but it is very slow(~1m) in android's chrome.

I've tried setting the value by doing :

```
$('#myTextarea').html(myDataUrl);
$('#myTextarea').text(myDataUrl);
$('#myTextarea').val(myDataUrl);
```

Comment: How long is your string approximately?

Comment: It can be as long as 15000 characters, longer strings are totally possible.

Comment: Don't bother I figured out a way to make it work. I just needed to not display the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put display:none on the textarea as it was what I intended to do later. 
I think not doing the text input animation saves a lot of time.